# Is AES more secure than Rijndael?

Tags: encryption, aes

Which algorithm is generally considered to be more secure, and is AES-192/AES-256 still considered to be secure?

After reading [this](http://phys.org/news/2011-08-world-toughest-encryption-scheme-vulnerable.html) it's lead me to belive that the Rijndael algorithm would be a more secure choice, but is this actually true?

Comment: AES is Rijndael with some parameters specifically set to safe choices.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AES is a subset of Rijndael ([FIPS-197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf)). It's still being considered secure, if you continue reading to the bottom of the article:

> Even if the largest botnet ever discovered – the
>   30-million-computer-strong BredoLab botnet – was given the task of
>   attacking an AES-256 implementation, the sheer number of possible
>   combinations would make the task virtually impossible.

The attack you suggested is called a biclique attack and is slightly faster than it would take to bruteforce an AES key. Considering that would still be a a few trillion years it's not really feasable.

Also this is the  [official press release](http://www.esat.kuleuven.be/scd/docs/110817_Barst%20in%20AES_ENG.pdf) from the Katholieke Universiteit Leuven about the code being broken. (This is the university where both AES and the attack against it were made)